# Frequent inserts into sorted collection

Tags: c#, .net, performance, collections

I have sorted collection (List) and I need to keep it sorted at all times.

I am currently using List.BinarySearch on my collection and then insert element in right place. I have also tried sorting list after every insertion but the performance in unacceptable.

Is there a solution that will give better performance? Maybe I should use other collection.

(I am aware of SortedList but it is restricted to unique keys)

Comment: What is the type you are sorting on ?...string, int, other..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PowerCollections](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/) has an `OrderedBag` type which may be good for what you need. From the docs

> **Inserting**, deleting, and looking up an
>   an element all are done in **log(N) + M
>   time**, where N is the number of keys in
>   the tree, and M is the current number
>   of copies of the element being
>   handled.

However, for the .NET 3.5 built in types, using `List.BinarySearch` and inserting each item into the correct place is a good start - but that uses an Array internally so your performance will drop due to all the copying you're doing when you insert.

If you can group your inserts into batches that will improve things, but unless you can get down to only a single sort operation after all your inserting you're probably better off using `OrderedBag` from `PowerCollections` if you can.

Comment: PowerCollections and its OrderedBag is great however I ended up using a Priority Queue (also not available in the .NET)

Comment: is this still the case 6 years later?

Comment: @mcmillab I haven't looked at the perf, but if I needed this today I'd start with [C5 Collections](https://github.com/sestoft/C5) and look at [TreeBag](https://c5docs.azurewebsites.net/class_c5_1_1_tree_bag.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using .Net 4, you can use a `SortedSet<T>`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx

For .Net 3.5 and lower, see if a `SortedList<TKey,TValue>` works for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx

Comment: SortedSet won't allow duplicates. And neither will SortedList

Answer (score 1):

Try to aggregate insertions into batches, and sort only at the end of each batch.